# how do I get a cell of data from a specific row in c# with a local sql database file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

So im pretty much just messing with c# and sql databases and I created a database with a table that has 2 columns, one for username and one for password and I wanted to know how i would look up the row the username is in and get the corresponding password(cell next to it) so I could compare for a login aspx page

Comment: How are you accessing your data?  Using a SqlCommand object, using linq2Sql, or something else, or are you just at the point where you're trying to figure out what you need to use to access your data?

Comment: **Never** store passwords in plain text.  You should use secure hashing (not MD5) with salt.

Comment: @SLaks True, but I'm guessing he is just learning this stuff and hasn't gotten that far yet.

Comment: @SLaks: thanks for the tip! but Brandon is correct

Comment: @Brandon Moore thats what I'm asking. I have the database in my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question that is going to take you doing a bit of research.  There are a plethora of tutorials on the internet on how to access data.  Below I've included one way that you can return a single value for you to get started with.  You'll need to include System.Data.SqlClient.

```
// See http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for how to build your connection string
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
Object returnValue;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

I lifted this example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeb84awz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You'll probably want to learn linq2sql or linq2entities eventually, but I would learn to use the classes provided in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace first.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong approach. Collect both the username and password, and look to see if there is a match in the database.

How to do it in C#? I like LINQ to SQL, even thought Microsoft recommends otherwise. Create a LINQ to SQL classes object in a C# project, call it `MyContextClass`, drop your database objects onto it. Then, in your code behind, write something like:

```
using (MyContextClass ctx = new MyContextClass) {
    if (ctx.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Username == txtUsername.Text && f.Password == txtPassword.Text) != null) {
        // The user got it right.
    }
}
```

However, all the warnings about storing passwords in the comments above really do apply. Integrating those is left as an exercise for the user.

Comment: Sorry I worded the question weirdly. I'll change it now, but when I say look up the username, I mean find the row the username is in(hopefully just a for loop) and then get the value of the cell next to it. Sorry!

Comment: None of that changes my answer. You have a great deal to learn before any of us can answer the question with less than the actual solution to your problem.

Comment: And your link is of no use to me... I know c# just not how to access databases...

Comment: @vbman11 you are thinking about database tables the wrong way.  SQL works on sets you don't iterate through to find the data you want you define a set that contains the data you want.